# FLUTTER- FETCH DATA FROM JSON LIST

Tags: json, database, flutter, dart

I have some problem that I cannot solve, please help me. I want to fetch data from database, and this data is json list... I wrote some code but I could not print on the console... I will add the code below, please help me... I guess I have to use for loop but when I tried I can just fetch 1 data...

codes below here:

```
class DenemeParca extends StatefulWidget {
  final String parcaReferans;

  DenemeParca({this.parcaReferans});

  @override
  _DenemeParcaState createState() => _DenemeParcaState();
}

Future<List<dynamic>> getIhaleData() async {
  final url =
      'https://www.ekspar.com.tr/onarim/dart.php';
  var response = await http.get(url);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}

String _parcaReferans(dynamic user) {
  for (var i = 8; i < 40; i++) {
    return user['parca_adi']['$i'];
  }
}

class _DenemeParcaState extends State<DenemeParca> {
  Widget _buildBody() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      future: getIhaleData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      print(_parcaReferans(snapshot.data[index]));
                    },
                    child: Text('Get Data'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Ekspar Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: DenemeParca() 
    ),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DenemeParca();
  }
}
```

by the way link has the json codes, thank you...

Comment: The JSON in your API keeps changing can you fix that?

Comment: sorry my friend, I was trying to do it ://

Comment: let me know when you are done with it so that I can answer your question

Comment: it didn't work,i have still same error... I mean I didn't change anything

Comment: the link in your code does not contain 'parca_referans'.

Comment: yes it is just convert to 'parca_adi'

Comment: I have posted an answer which should solve your problem.

Comment: thx bro, it worked well!! but you know is there any solution for this by using loop?

Comment: convert "1" : "somedata" into an JSON array like ["somedata","somedata2","somedata3"'. Then change your model accordingly using that website and then you will be able to loop over these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your 'parcaAdi' is not a JSON array so you can't loop over all the values, instead you have to select each of them one by one. To fetch all the data I first created a Model for your JSON using this [website](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/). Now to fetch your data you can just do.

```dart
Future getIhaleData() async {
  final url =
      'https://www.ekspar.com.tr/onarim/dart-ilan-listele.php?parca_ilan_id=111';
  var response = await http.get(url);
  Model model = Model.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)[0]);
  // now you can access your data.
  print(model.parcaAdi.s1);
  print(model.parcaAdi.s2);
}
```

Here is the code for the model class.

```dart
class Model {
  ParcaAdi parcaAdi;

  Model({this.parcaAdi});

  Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    parcaAdi =
        json['parca_adi'] != null ? ParcaAdi.fromJson(json['parca_adi']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (parcaAdi != null) {
      data['parca_adi'] = parcaAdi.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class ParcaAdi {
  String s1;
  String s2;
  String s3;
  String s4;
  String s5;
  String s6;
  String s7;
  String s8;

  ParcaAdi(
      {this.s1, this.s2, this.s3, this.s4, this.s5, this.s6, this.s7, this.s8});

  ParcaAdi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    s1 = json['1'];
    s2 = json['2'];
    s3 = json['3'];
    s4 = json['4'];
    s5 = json['5'];
    s6 = json['6'];
    s7 = json['7'];
    s8 = json['8'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['1'] = s1;
    data['2'] = s2;
    data['3'] = s3;
    data['4'] = s4;
    data['5'] = s5;
    data['6'] = s6;
    data['7'] = s7;
    data['8'] = s8;
    return data;
  }
}
```